# SignalR over websocket timeout issue

Tags: signalr

Our system now defaults to web-sockets for our signalr communications.

When I send a whole bunch of data the web socket seems to time out after about 2-3 seconds.  Setting the transport to 'longPolling' works just fine.  I do not see anywhere where a timeout needs to be set for a web-socket explicitly.

How do I prevent the web-socket transport from timing out when sending large amounts of data in one go?

Edit:

We are using the javascript client on version 1.1.3 and sending apparently more than 2 seconds worth of data :) --- I am sending 500 message structures with each being around 90 bytes.

But it seems something else may be going on as the messages are sent one-by-one.

Comment: A few questions: How much data are you sending? Are you using the javascript client?

Comment: I have the same problem at the moment. Were you able to solve this? I'm using SignalR 2.0.3

Comment: I am also facing the same issue below are server logs

Information: 0 : Connection f... is New.
Information: 0 : Timeout(f...)
Information: 0 : End(f...)
Verbose: 0 : Cancel(f...)
Verbose: 0 : DrainWrites(f...)
Information: 0 : CompleteRequest (f...)
Information: 0 : CloseSocket(f...)
Verbose: 0 : Connection f... exists. Closing previous connection.
Information: 0 : Timeout(f...)